# Can't resolve NullPointerException thrown by my toString

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to check if my user's data in my `Firebase` console is not empty, or isn't an empty string. To do this I use `DataSnapshot`. When I try using `dataSnapshot.getValue().toString() my toString()` is throwing a `NullPointerException`. I'm unsure how to resolve this, in this context. Please help.

```
public void checkIfUserDataExists(){

        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

            userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user_profile_info").child(userID);

            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Log.i("snapshot data", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                    if (!dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().isEmpty() && !dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().equals("")) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

---

```
2019-08-02 16:01:31.581 28329-28329/com.example.seansandroid.dementiaapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.seansandroid.dementiaapp, PID: 28329
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.seansandroid.dementiaapp.Login.SignInActivity$2.onDataChange(SignInActivity.java:137)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

This occurred because I deleted some input data from my database to try and check something. Now, because there is no data in the `dataSnapshot`, the `toString()` is throwing a `NullPointerException`. Is there anyway for me to make this point to an empty string instead of null?

Comment: Check `getValue()` isn’t `null` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test for non null dataSnapshot.getValue()

```
public void checkIfUserDataExists(){

        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

            userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user_profile_info").child(userID);

            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Log.i("snapshot data", "dataSnapshot.getValue() = " + dataSnapshot.getValue());

                    if ((dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) && !dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().isEmpty() && !dataSnapshot.getValue().toString().equals("")) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: This perfectly solved my problem. I'm sad to see the Log.i go, but its worth it for the app to work! Thanks, Mat!

Comment: If you want the log, you can call Log.i("snapshot data", "dataSnapshot.getValue() = " + dataSnapshot.getValue()); If dataSnapshot.getValue() is null, it will print null instead of throwing a null pointer exception

Answer (score 1):

You can use [exits()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#exists()) method by Firebase to check wether the datasnapshot exits.

```java
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        Log.i("snapshot data", "dataSnapshot.getValue() = " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else {

        Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Careful, this code will throw a NullPointerException on Log.i("snapshot data", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()); when dataSnapshot.getValue() is null

Comment: Wow, I didn't know of this method. Still quite new to android and Firebase. Your answer eliminates the toString problem in my dataSnapshot.getValue().toString() but doesn't deal with the Log. Although its deletable or easily wrapped in an if. That's very much.

Comment: Thanks @matdev for pointing it out, I just updated the answer